# Delete the value of route_number in BroadcastReceiver when the WIFI is turn off

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi, android-wifi

I am parsing JSON text file with this structure

```
{
     "ssid": "public hotspot", 
     "route_number": 4
}
```

in the BroadcastReceiverListener but I am facing problem when I turn the WiFi off, the `route_number` has the last value `4` and not `0`. What I want to reach is, in case of turning off the WiFi to set `route_number` to 0 and not always getting the last value.

How can I reach that?

`MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int route_number;
    TextView textWifi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textWifi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textWifi);

        wifi_receiver = new BroadcastReceiverListener();
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifi.startScan();
    }

    private class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();

            if (updatedResults.size() > 0) {
                String ssid = deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
                // retrieve data from json String and parse it.
                route_number = parse_SSID(ssid);
                textWifi.setText(String.valueOf(route_number));
            } else {
                textWifi.setText("There is no WiFi in range.");

            }
        }

        private int parse_SSID(String ssid) {
            int route_number = 0;

            InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ssid_number);
            Reader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            WiFiJSONList obj = gson.fromJson(rd, WiFiJSONList.class);
            // Now iterate through the list
            List<WifiJSON> wifijson = obj.getWifiList();
            Iterator<WifiJSON> iterator = wifijson.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                WifiJSON wifielement = (WifiJSON) iterator.next();
                String ssid_name = wifielement.getSsid();

                if (ssid_name.equals(ssid)) {
                    route_number = wifielement.getRoute_number();
                }
            }
            return route_number;

        }

    }

    protected void onResume() {

        IntentFilter wifi = new IntentFilter();
        wifi.addAction(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, wifi);

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifi_receiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```